# Lost data on reload component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, reload

this's mine project: https://pokedex-vue-sf.netlify.app/

when i go on pokemon details and reload page I get 404 page.
How can I fix that? I tried with localStorage 
but I did not succeed

Comment: why does your route changes when the web page is refreshed? Are you doing anything in `mounted` or inside `router.js` file?

Comment: no, the path rest the same but the route-view switch from description.vue to notFound.vue

Answer (score 1):

1. It is because you're reloading '/pokemon/bulbasaur' route. You must configure your server to serve '/' for all routes.
2. Or you could toggle your history mode in your vue-router. This will add a '#' after your base url. Anything after # will not be sent to the server, so you will always be requesting the '/' route.

Comment: second option doesn't work, how can i do the first option?

Comment: It depends on your server. Check out https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html